# Stop uwsgi when code updating

Tags: python, linux, django, uwsgi

I use uwsgi for running my django-project. And now I search a way make "gracefully" update code. If I updates code when uwsgi running then I've got a many errors in log because some templates or files can be removed within updating code. So I need just stop uwsgi for awhile and restart it when updating code is done.

P.S. uwsgi works under non-root user and I deploy code under that non-root user too, so I can't just do:

```
uwsgi --stop pidfile.pid.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways to manage code reloads in uWSGI, the vast majority of them is described in this article: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html

Try to adapt the concepts described there with your specific situation

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind.

1. Stop uwsgi and restart when finished.
2. Deploy to a second directory. For example, assuming the app is pointed at /opt/app, then deploy the code to ~/app, and rm -rf /opt/app/* && cp -r ~/app/ /opt/app; You still may need to restart uwsgi in case it's hanging on to any FDs.